# The numbers $\binom{n}{p}\binom{m}{q}$, $\binom{l}{p}\binom{j}{q}$ and $\binom{d}{p}\binom{r}{q}$ have a common divisor.

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I am asking about the validity of the following claim

The numbers $\binom{n}{p}\binom{m}{q}$, $\binom{l}{p}\binom{j}{q}$ and $\binom{d}{p}\binom{r}{q}$ have a common divisor $>1$.

where the integers are all different.

Comment: Isn't $1$ a common divisor?

Comment: @NajKamp: the divisor must be $>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its false, take
$$
\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{1}, \binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}, \binom{6}{1}\binom{7}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is false as stated.  You could have $n=p, m=q$ and the first one is $1$ which has no divisors.  Are there some conditions on the variables?